# h:selectOneMenu is always enable when a p:dialog's modal attribute was set true. IE6

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

h:selectOneMenu is always enable when a p:dialog shows (the dialog's modal attribute was set true.) IE6

But, in IE8 or other browsers, it works well.

Comment: It's hard to visualize/understand your problem based on the as far given information. Please elaborate. If your English is bad, feel free to just include the minimum required code snippet which reproduces exactly this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you **have to** Support a 10 years old browser? Supporting IE6 is extremely expansive. The more JavaScript you need, the more Problems you will get.

Answer (score 0):

hm, sounds like you are refering to the select menu is visible even though it should be hidden behind other elements?

it is an ie6 problem with select boxes (and not a jsf problem), the solution i use is a component that contains the code below, that i include in any menus etc that might appear on top of select boxes

```
    <!-- hack: make the selectBoxes behind the div really hidden -->
<script>
document.write('&lt;!--[if lte IE 6.5]&gt;&lt;iframe src="javascript:false;"       
                   class="hiddenIframeMenu"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;');
</script>
```

the css:

```
.hiddenIframe { display:none; display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;z-index:-1; filter:mask(); width:3210px; height:3210px; }
```

more info about the bug + solution can be found here:

http://www.targetprocess.com/agileproductblog/2006/07/ie6-select-and-z-index-problem.html